# how to use mysql function inside cakephp2

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to make a simple query inside my model, I have already done the same thing in my controller, and so far it works.

```
/users/controller 
    $reservations = $db->fetchAll(
        "SELECT TIME_FORMAT(time_start, '%H:%i') as time_start, 
                TIME_FORMAT(time_end, '%H:%i') as time_end 
         FROM bookings 
         WHERE datepicker = ?", [$date]);
```

I know that solution is not efficient, so I wanted to create a method in my function to do the same thing, however I can't find a way to enclode the `time_start` field with the mysql function `TIME_FORMAT()` using `->find()` method.

#### update.

I have tried using [virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields) and I got only an `Indirect modification of overloaded property has no effect` error.

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post the complete error message including the full stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it it is available in a properly readable fashion)! Also show the proper context, ie the code that actually triggers the error! You're most certainly not doing it as shown in the answer of @drmonkeyninja, which should work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) for these. So in your case you'd want something like this:-

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'time_start' => "TIME_FORMAT(time_start, '%H:%i')",
    'time_end' => "TIME_FORMAT(time_end, '%H:%i')"
);
```

These are defined within the relevant model.

Comment: I have tried this actually. I think it was meant to work with previous versions of php, before on 5.6 I get `Indirect modification of overloaded property has no effect` error. I should actually update the anwer.